# EEPROM Problem (cant clear arduino-uno eeprom)

Tags: arduino-uno, eeprom

I have encountered problem with my Arduino Uno, I just recently started using arduino, and this is my first time to use the EEPROM. My problem is that I have created a password protected door, and due to several attempts I have stored so much password and I dont know which one is the correct, since it always prompts me "Wrong password". I have tried to:

1. display the password in the lcd using lcd.print

   *this made the lcd display characters with 111 and a character that looks like a 3 horizontal lines, I dont know how to input the 3 horizontal character lines on my keypad matrix*
2. tried to clear the EEPROM memory using the built-in arduino example (EEPROM_clear)

   *but to no avail, the password in the EEPROM is retained , and now I cant figure out the password*

**What should I do please help me :(**

Comment: try to modify the clear example to write FF. `EEPROM.write(i, FF);`

Comment: @Juraj sir it states that FF is not declared in the scope, I have copy pasted your sygegstion into `for (int i = 0 ; i < EEPROM.length() ; i++) {
    EEPROM.write(i, FF);`

Comment: sorry `EEPROM.write(i, 0xFF);`

Comment: @Juraj sir still not working :(